# GetRows on a RecordSet won't store text column from Access DB

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, excel

I've successfully connected to my Access database from excel, and can return the contents of the database in a string Using GetString on my RecordSet. GetString prints all of the contents of the table into a message box as I expect it to(in comments below), but GetRows ignores one of the columns(GCAT in this case), which happens to be the only text field in the database. I am trying to print a particular instance of this field into my excel sheet, but at array position(0,1), where the GCAT field should be, it prints the third item of the record, and not the second as I expect. What am I missing? Does it have something to do with it being a text field? Maybe i'm using the wrong library or database engine? Every other column in the database is returned normally.

```vb
Sub Connect()
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConn As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim arrayString As String



sConn = "Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Data Source='<path_to_db>'; Persist Security Info='False';"

' Open a connection.
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.ConnectionString = sConn
oConn.Open

' Make a query over the connection.
sSQL = "SELECT ID, GCAT, Min_Years, Max_Years, Contract_Price FROM GCAT"
Set oRs = New ADODB.Recordset
CursorLocation = adUseClient
oRs.Open sSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText


GCATArray = oRs.GetRows()

Sheets("Calculations").Range("D6").Value = GCATArray(0, 1)

'GCATString = oRs.GetString()
'MsgBox GCATString

' Close the connection.
oConn.Close
Set oConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is my first foray in VB so I'm both confused and struggling with the language to being with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see any obvious faults in your code, have you tried debugging yourself? You can loop the fields in the recordset, and display their names for testing like so:

```
For i = 0 To oRS.Fields.Count -1
    debug.print oRS.Fields(i).Name
Next
```

That way, you can see whether the field you are looking for is actually there in the first place. Next, you can access the field your're after by doing:

```
Do While Not oRS.EOF
    Debug.Print oRS!GCAT
    'Exit Do 'if you want to display only the first, break out of the loop here
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

You don't need the GetRows() in this case, that should give you a performance boost too (very noticible on larger recordsets).

Comment: I never really solved the original problem, but you gave me access to the fields I needed with that second block. Thanks!